# Python numpy array strange error

Tags: python

I have a rather large numpy array for a game I am making for python. Numpy returns an error on a comma. This is my array.

```
import numpy as np

111 x = np.array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2],
                  [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3], 
                  [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3],
                  [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], 
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3],
                  [4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4], 
                  [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3], 
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],n13int43)
111 type(x)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'2
111 x.shape
(56, 43)
111 x.dtype
dtype('into.')
```

and here is the error

File "maingame.py", line 3

```
111 x = np.array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                                                                                                                                                                    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I've already tried just deleting the comma and replacing it again, and its the same error

Comment: you need one more bracked between `2],n13int43` as: `2]],n13int43`

Comment: In the future, try to find a *minimal* failing case.  If you had simply deleted some of the rows, you would have still had an error, but you would have had a smaller problem to solve.  This is especially true in the case of SyntaxErrors, where you can even remove code necessary for it to actually *run*, as you only need to see if it can be *parsed*.

Comment: I made the small version and the error message was the same but this time on x. it is 2x2 grid. the big version when I added the second bracket it had the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another bracket like this `2]],n13int43`. Also Try to find out your mistakes using a minimal case. Always use Python shell for these basic errors!